# What is .CONTENT_URI

Tags: java, android

I'm looking at the following snip of code from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

```
// Query for all people contacts using the Contacts.People convenience class.
// Put a managed wrapper around the retrieved cursor so we don't have to worry about
// requerying or closing it as the activity changes state.
mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(mCursor);
```

I'm just wondering, what exactly does .CONTENT_URI do? I see they are trying to list all of the instances of class People.

Answer (score 2):

"Content" can come from anywhere in your device. The system as well as every app can provide content.

Those Uris act similar to http urls and help identify the data source that provides the information (`http://phonebook.com`). An Uri goes in practice 1 step further and identifies at least the table inside a database (`http://phonebook.com/by_name`), sometimes even the exact item. (e.g. `http://phonebook.com/by_name/macdonjo`) - or like `content://com.android.contacts/123` in reality.

So `CONTENT_URI` does nothing besides telling `ContentResolver` what data to fetch.

P.s. the code you've found there looks pretty dated. Both managing cursor as well as the `People` convenience class are deprecated for a while now.